# problem with lookdev mode?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, render-layers

I'm using Blender from a 1-month.

I don't know what happened suddenly it changed to *Material Preview* mode no lighting no environment scene.

Even after pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> key to go to *LookDev* mode even there it is replaced by material preview.

I have checked tick mark some light and scene in render mode. What is the default setup?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the shading tab and making sure that "scene world" and "scene lights" are off, unless of course you're using an HDRI map.

[image: image of the shading tab]

If that doesn't help then make sure you're using Eevee -> [image: scene render engine selection]